# Make pandas dataframe column of length of lists in entries on other column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Suppose I have the dataframe:

```
 df=pd.DataFrame(data={'col1':[[1,4,4,1],[2,3]],'col2':[[1,2],[1,5,2,4]]})
```

How can I add a new column to this dataframe whose entry at every row is the length of the corresponding list in, say, col1?

Comment: Use `df['col1'].str.len()`

Answer (score 0):

use `str.len()`

```
df['length'] = df.col1.str.len()

print(df)
           col1          col2  length
0  [1, 4, 4, 1]        [1, 2]       4
1        [2, 3]  [1, 5, 2, 4]       2
```